# Using Markov properties to express probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Consider a discrete time Markov chain with transition probabilities $p(i,j)$, and assume $X_0 = 3$. Express $$P(X_6 = 7, X_5 = 3 | X_4 = 1, X_9 = 3)$$ in terms of the (if necessary multi-step) transition probabilities.

My current work is as follows:

$$P(X_6 = 7, X_5 = 3 | X_4 = 1, X_9 = 3) = P(X_6 = 7, X_5 = 3 | X_4 = 1)$$ $$= P(X_6 = 7 | X_5 = 3, X_4 = 1) P(X_5 = 3 | X_4 = 1)$$ $$= P(X_6 = 7 | X_5 = 3) P(X_5 = 3 | X_4 = 1)$$ $$= P(X_1 = 7 | X_0 = 3) P(X_1 = 3 | X_0 = 1)$$ $$= p(3,7) p(1,3)$$

Have I made some mistake here, or is this valid? I'm a bit thrown off since they give that $X_0 = 3$, but since the probability they ask about has $X_4 = 1$ given, we don't need to know anything about $X_0$, right?

Comment: You say that $$P(X_6 = 7, X_5 = 3 | X_4 = 1, X_9 = 3) = P(X_6 = 7, X_5 = 3 | X_4 = 1)$$ Oops, why?

Comment: @Did I suppose this just seemed an intuitive conclusion to make - sorry, I'm still very new to this. My thinking is that the probability of some event happening (in the current state) conditioned on some future state surely would be independent of that future state. Although I'm sure there is some simple example to disprove this.

Comment: Yes there are simple counterexamples. Why not quitting "intuition" for a while (whatever you mean by this rather slippery notion) and stick to mathematical definitions?

Comment: @Did I think this is easier said than done - but certainly something that needs to be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Chain Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)) and the Markov property.

$$
\begin{align}
P(X_6=5,X_5=3|X_4=1,X_9=3)=\frac{P(X_9=3,X_6=5,X_5=3,X_4=1)}{P(X_9=3,X_4=1)}\\
=\frac{P(X_9=3|X_6=5)P(X_6=5|X_5=3)P(X_5=3|X_4=1)P(X_4=1)}{P(X_9=3|X_4=1)P(X_4=1)}\\
=\frac{P(X_9=3|X_6=5)P(X_6=5|X_5=3)P(X_5=3|X_4=1)}{P(X_9=3|X_4=1)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I see - it still seems odd in my mind that $$P(X_6 = 5, X_5 = 3 | X_4 = 1, X_9 = 3) =!= P(X_6 = 5, X_5 = 3 | X_4 = 1)$$ I'm going to have to remind myself that I can't make this conclusion. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm now getting $$= \frac{p^3(5,3) p(3,5) p(1,3)}{p^5(1,3)}$$ Does this look correct?

Comment: It looks OK to me